# Wordpress Theme Breaking on Migration to Live Site

Tags: themes, child-theme, migration

I've developed a Wordpress site locally and have recently been trying to upload it to the server. Although every time I do so, the child theme I have created for the parent seems to break.

I can't figure out why this is, as I can't see anything that has changed. It says that "the parent theme is missing. Please install the "Propulsion" parent theme." although it is clearly there, and can be activated.

It might be worth mentioning too that when I originally migrated the site, nothing would show up when I tried to visit the site, not even an error message. Support from Dreamhost then told me that no theme was activated, and activated the default theme for me. It was from here that I could see the error with the child theme.

I would just try and delete and reinstall the child theme, although when I do so I lose all of my theme options, custom templates etc. which have taken me quite a while to build, so really would be terrible if I had to start from scratch.

Is there a way I can perhaps export all this data from my local copy if I can't get it working through a normal migration? I'm testing all this on a mirror of the site through Dreamhost, i'm not sure if that might have anything to do with the problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i've been battling with this for a while and am getting a little desperate!

Thanks again,

Jack

Comment: try to activate errors display on your localhost in your .htaccess and share the errors you are getting...

Answer (score 1):

How did you migrate the site from your local machine to dreamhose? sometimes themes and plugins save the actual path to their file in the options table, and most likely the path at dreamhost is not the same as at your localhost. It is worth trying to use phpmyadmin to inspect the options table and try to detect values that hold the old URl or path from your local machine and fix them

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Mark. I'll have a look into that. I bought backupbuddy to migrate the site so was hoping it might take care of these sorts of problems!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error was a compatibility issue with mixed case identifiers (such as Propulsion instead of propulsion in the Template definition of my child theme css).

Thanks for your help guys!

---